# Uninstall Old Fedora OS and Install Ubuntu along side Win 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, uninstall

I have installed Fedora alongside Win 7 Ultimate 64 bit. I have decided to uninstall the Fedora and I want to use Ubuntu instead. I wish to keep Win 7 and its data (NTFS drives). Please guide me how to do so.

My main concern is to uninstall and existing Linux OS without rupturing the Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First backup your important datas which was placed on that Fedora partition.
- Now boot from the Ubuntu installation disk or live disk.
- Click on Install Ubuntu option on startup and select something else option.
- Now format the fedora partition into ext4 filesystem and then install Ubuntu on the formatted ext4 partition.
- When the installer asks you to create a new swap partition then follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) to allocate how much space needed for the SWAP partition.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!! Will do as suggested :-) Cheers

Comment: I would like to run .exe applications on Ubuntu. How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you know about [wine](http://www.winehq.org/)?It's awesome.

Comment: Yeah I have heard about that client. but i have not tried it.

Comment: I have plenty of questions popping in my mind now.. :-P.. Does ubuntu comes with pre installed mp3 and video codecs plugins? Or do  i have to download it manually?

Comment: Accept my answer.Earn 20 rep on this site,come [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company) and ping me.I will answer all of your questions.

Comment: no,you have to install ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq. This is what I get when i click on the chatroom link.